# Facebook Share Dialog | Not showing correct details like name, description

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework, ionic2, fbsdksharedialog

I am working with `Facebook Share Dialog` When i call the Facebook Sharedialog it always get the data from `href`.

Code snippet -

```
 this.facebook.showDialog({
                    method: 'share',
                    href: 'https://google.com',
                    name: 'Name',
                    picture: 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg',
                    description: 'Description'
                });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See changelog v2.9 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.9

> 90-Day Breaking Changes
>
> The following fields are deprecated for edges and dialogs that allow 
>   attaching links to posts:
>
> - caption
> - description
> - name
> - picture
> - thumbnail

This was changed to prevent users from using wrong OG Tags if they do not own the URL. Use OG Tags on the shared URL instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/

Comment: Can you please share all the og tags for my requirements?

Comment: added a link about og tags